# Converting Multiple Picture to byte array in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

i have one questions, how to convert Multiple picture to byte array (byte []), cause i have case to save many picture in my database sqlite, i have array list which contains picture in drawable folder..

```
 ArrayList<Integer> imageId = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
    imageId.add(R.drawable.a1);
    imageId.add(R.drawable.a2);
    imageId.add(R.drawable.a3);
    imageId.add(R.drawable.a4);
    imageId.add(R.drawable.a5);
```

Then i have tried this code to convert into byte arrray

```
    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.a1);
    //calculate how many bytes our image consists of.
    int bytes = b.getByteCount();
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes); //Create a new buffer
    b.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer); //Move the byte data to the buffer
    byte[] array = buffer.array();
    System.out.println(array);
```

The code below is working, but the problem is how the code below is convert one picture, and now i need to convert multiple picture in arrayList, can anybody help me? cause i have tried with looping, it give me an error, java.lang.OutOfMemoryError..

Comment: Why don't you show the problematic loop?

Comment: @CL.when i use looping the problem is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Comment: Simply, you can not.. It's impossible to keep lots of bytes in memory try another solution.

Comment: @SercanOzdemir:okay, so can you help me about this case.. in my apps work in offline mode, so i tried to include all my data into database project, and i want to include many images in my database, can u give some reference, and tutorial, cause i new developing android.. Thx

Comment: What do you mean by that : `in my apps work in offline mode, so i tried to include all my data into database project, and i want to include many images in my database`

Comment: @SercanOzdemir: so i include all my data in device not from the server..

Comment: you mean you are trying to pick pictures from device and upload to server ?

Comment: @SercanOzdemir no", i mean i want to include a data when the apps is installed, usually when we downloading game like Brave Frontier, and after install it, we have to wait the to download a data again right? so i mean when i install my apss, i don't really need to download the data again, after the instalation proccess, sorry my bad language..

Comment: i see now, please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

first of all do not save whole pictures to SqLite. It is not a suitable way. There's a very easy solution but a little risky..

Just save images to `SD Card` as `WhatsApp` do and save their path to SqLite. So whenever you want to access your pictures you can read their paths from Sqlite and access them.

But the risk is pictures are in user control, so they can remove it. But you can hide the pictures in a deep way :)

Comment: okay i get, so i must installed the apps first and get path picture from SD card right?